# MPMoviePlayerViewController playhead (time) notifications

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications, mpmoviewcontroller

I'm just wanting to know what the playhead of my movie has changed, but I'm not finding a list of notifications online anywhere (I thought for sure apple would have that info).

Anyway, does anyone know the notification name I should be watching for? I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notification on playback progress or prebuffering progress. Both information are available via simple properties of the `MPMoviePlayerController` ([see its reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and its implemented protocol `MPMediaPlayback` ([see its reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback)).

```
currentPlaybackTime
```

> The current position of the playhead. (required)

```
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime
```

> Discussion
>
> For video-on-demand or progressively downloaded content, this value is
>   measured in seconds from the beginning of the current item. Changing
>   the value of this property moves the playhead to the new location. For
>   content streamed live from a server, this value represents the time
>   from the beginning of the playlist when it was first loaded.

---

```
playableDuration
```

> The amount of currently playable content. (read-only)

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval playableDuration
```

> Discussion
>
> For progressively downloaded network content, this property
>   reflects the amount of content that can be played now.

---